# How do I write a name of a person when it is called from far away

Tags: перевод

I know it sounds a stupid question but in English comics, if someone is calling a woman named "Laura" from afar, you write "Lauraaaaaaa", with the last letter repeated.
How do I do the same with "Катя" in Russian?
If I write "Катяяяяяяя" it seems like I am saying "Katyayayayaya" instead of "Katyaaaaaaa".
How do you do that?

Comment: Подружка ей с улицы кричит:
— Ка-тя-а-а!!!
Катя ей с дивана отвечает:
— Че-го-о-о?

Comment: _"in english comics, if someone is calling a woman named "Laura" from afar, you write "Lauraaaaaaa", with the last letter repeated"_ Not necessarily. There are a few ways to do it, and sometimes it depends on the name.

Comment: Of course "not necessarily"... mine was just an example to make my question clearer.

Comment: According the norm, Катя-а-а-а!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you write in Russian, you can write "Катяяяяя". No one would read it as "Катя-йа-йа-йа". "Катяаааа" looks unusual but can be used in situation when the last sound is transformed in a shout like "Катяяяааааааа".

If you write in English it's better to write "Katyaaaa".

Note that in Russian often the stressed vowel is shouted long too, not only the last one - so you can also write "Каааатяяяя" or "Владииииимиииир".

Comment: We say "It's better to... write". "you better" translates more to "тебе полагается, тебе положено" "ты должен" not "тебе лучше". Русские часто делают эту ошибку.))

Comment: @VCH250 Oh, sorry and thank you :) Good to know!

Comment: Nobody writes, sorry, should write the name like you do. There are certain requirements for written speech. I wrote an example above.Congrats!

Comment: @VCH250 Thank you, I didn't know that "you better" is imperative!

Answer (score 13):

That depends on whether you want the literary norm or something informal you could use, say, on the internet.

The literary norm would be **Ка-а-атя-а-а**. Note the hyphen before each vowel repetition. I'm surprised no-one else brought it up. To answer your specific question, the modifying letters do revert to their non-modifier counterparts in repetitions (hence **Я-а-ана** and **Ю-у-ур!**). Keep the number of repetitions down to one or two. Three or four would mean it's *really* drawn-out. More than that means it's a children's story or the writer's got an amateurish fondness for typographic mannerisms.

In informal writing, **Кааатяяяя** is perfectly fine and you can hold down the key much more liberally.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually I'm surprised with the answers given. As a native speaker I'd rather will stretch the stressed vowel, something like "Ау, Каааааааатя! Ты где?"

The same rule will apply to any name. 
So now let's consider what happen if `я` is stressed, then actually indeed something like "Ну Яяяяяяян, ну чего ты копаешься". So я (or ю - Юююююр) does not usually turned into "йааааа" (ой "йуyyy") - it's just that it's pronounced that way.

'Ё' is slightly different story, it's quit often ommited but still you'd rather see "ёёёёёёжик"  or just "ееееежик" but never  "йоооожик".

Comment: Funnily enough, that's what I'd do in English, too.

Answer (score -2):

"Катяяяяя" looks OK. You repeat a letter not a sound. я is a letter.

also I find "Катяяааааааа" OK.

Answer (score -2):

Katya-a-a-a and Katy-ia-ia-ia are the same